# Simulation experiment screen - edit box "action" dynamic change on condition

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have two edit boxes on my simulation experiment screen prior to running the model, one box for a minimum value, and the other for a maximum value.

I want the value within the minimum edit box to be equal to the value within the maximum edit box if the user ever inputs a value that is higher than the latter.

Something like this :

mininum box = 10
maximum box = 15

*User tries to do:*

minimum box = 20

*End result*

minumum box = 15
maximum box = 15

I tried this below in the "action" properties of my Edit Box element, but it hasn't worked.

```
if(min > max){
     min = max;
     value = Integer.toString(max);
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this in the min-box action code:

```
if (value >= maxEditbox.getValue()) {
    minEditBox.setValue(maxEditbox.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Thank you Benjamin! It worked perfectly.

For posterity, the value within an edit box is a String object, and needs to be converted before comparing (or replace it with minEditBox.getIntValue()). Also the function for changing the value within an edit box is setText().

Comment: fair enough, this was from my head :)